# Codename One - addCommand doesn't add a menu

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to add multiple commands to my `Form` in Codename One, we used to use a regular `Form` without `commandBehavior` but that caused some issues so I added it.

This is what the old version looked liked
[image]
And this is what the new version looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch `addCommand()` to `getToolbar().addCommandToOverflow()` or better yet `getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu*`. You can also use one of the other `getToolbar().addMaterialCommand*` methods to add an icon with the command. This results in more consistent behavior between platforms.

Comment: I don't make use of a `Toolbar` so it's returning as null when trying to `addCommandToOverflowMenu()`

Comment: You should set global toolbar to true, the old approach without the toolbar stopped working in newer versions of Android

Comment: Then I get a hamburger menu which I would like to avoid if at all possible. Is there any way to hide that?

Comment: That happens when you invoke `addCommandToSideMenu` or similar API's. It won't appear if you don't make that call. Unlike the old `addCommand` `Toolbar` lets you control every aspect